# Direct Line API Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: javascript, bots, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I have published my bot to Azure. Now I'm going to develop own chat UI. 
I want to use Direct Line API in JavaScript to call the bot.

How do I use Direct Line API in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct Line API just has 6 methods:

- Start a new conversation
- Get messages in a conversation
- Send a message
- Upload files and send as attachments
- Renew a token for a conversation
- Generate a token for a new conversation

Using these methods you can implement a bot in your own chat UI. In the following link you'll find extended documentation https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline/#navtitle.

My suggestion for NodeJS is use the 'request' package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday, `DirectLine` for `JavaScript` was published. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) is the source code and instructions on how to use it. You might want to consider using it if you don't want to use the out of the box web chat ([which was made public](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) some time ago)